# Timeout problem while surfing on the internet

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, timeout

While surfing with any browser (Internet Explorer 8, FireFox v3.6, FireFox v4, Chrome 11, Safari) some pages get `timeout` randomly. When I try at `safe mode` it works normally. What can it be?

- I thought if it is a virus/trojan problem and searched for it and cannot find any. (I know it doesn't mean if I didn't find any virus it doesn't exist.)
- I thought if it is because of my ZoneAlarm and uninstalled it and nothing changed.
- I was using cFosSpeed to organize my network packages and uninstalled it and nothing changed.

Waiting your suggestions.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. changing DNS didn't help. Interestingly it is happening mostly on local/Intranet servers

Answer (score 0):

Are you running FireFox? If so, when you start it up in safe mode, you are prompted with several options (disable addons, etc.). What options are you choosing?

If you are choosing all of the options, then I'd recommend that you choose one option at a time until you find one that causes the problem. If it is the extensions, then it might be that there is a particular one that is causing the problems.

Comment: I tried all my browsers (IE8, FF3.6, FF4, Chrome 11, Safari)

Comment: @pichoscosama Well, at this point I am making educated guesses because I'm not familiar with your setup. However, try setting youd DNS server to point to something NOT acquired by DHCP and most likely provided by your ISP. Try Google's for example (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4)